# Prove equivalence between these statements of the nilradical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $N$ be the nilradical ($=\{r\in R: r^n = 0 \text{ for a }n\in \mathbb{N}^*\})$
>
> Now prove $N=\mathrm{rad}(0)$ (where $\mathrm{rad}(I) = \{r\in R: r^n\in I \text{ for a }n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$) and then prove equivalence between:
>
> 1. $R$ has a unique prime ideal
> 2. each element of $R$ is either nilpotent or a unit
> 3. $R/N$ is a field

In a previous exercise I've proven that for an ideal $I\trianglelefteq R$ the $\mathrm{rad}(I) = I \Leftrightarrow I=\bigcap_j P_j$ where $P_j$ are prime ideals in $R$

I've managed to prove $3. \Leftrightarrow 2.$ and $1. \Rightarrow 3.$ But I'm somewhat stuck on proving $3. \Rightarrow 1.$ or $2. \Rightarrow 1.$

#### What I've tried

$2. \Rightarrow 1.$

Notice how $N$ is a prime ideal, choose a $pq\in N$ then $p^nq^n=0$ for a certain $n$. If now $p\not \in N$ then $p \in R^\times$ and from $p^nq^n=0$ we deduce $q^n=0$ which implies $q\in N$.

Now I have to prove that it is the unique prime ideal. Let $P$ be another prime ideal. Then $P\subseteq N$ since for each $p\in P$ then $p$ must be in $N$ or in $R^\times$. But since $P$ is a prime ideal the latter is excluded.

I don't see why $P\subsetneq N$ is impossible. I guess I have to show that $N\setminus P = \varnothing$ (I don't see any other way to tackle the issue). But how should I do this?

Hints **instead** of full solutions would be appreciated, I think it's something easy that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $x \in N$, so that $x^{n} = 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $P$ be any prime ideal; then $P$ contains zero, as does any ideal. Hence, $x^{n} \in P$; using the primality of $P$, what can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned you’ve seen the definition using the intersection of all prime ideals, and that makes it obvious that a prime ideal can’t be properly contained in $N$.

It’s easy to see by elements too that $N$ is contained in all primes.  Suppose $x\in N$, then $x^n=0\in P$ for every prime ideal $P$, then...

Comment: Actually I haven't seen the definition using the intersection of *all* prime ideals, but $\mathrm{rad}(I)=I\Leftrightarrow I=\cap_j P_j$ for *some* $P_j\trianglelefteq R$ prime ideals. The second method makes it easy though, thanks :)